# XPath select the next tab/col

Tags: html, xml, xpath, scrapy

I'm trying to scrap certain elements like "East to West" from "Label:" in html.

```
<div class="product-details">
  <dl>
    <dt>Label:</dt>
    <dd>
      East to West
      <br>
      </br>
    </dd>
    <dt>Subtitles:</dt>
    <dd>
      ----
      <br>
      </br> 
    </dd>
  </dl>
</div>
```

Here's what I tested in shell:

> response.xpath('//dl[dt =
>   "Label:"]/following-sibling::text()').extract_first()

it only returns

```
'\r\n\t'
```

I've explored a little deeper into the code, but it seems "East to West" is neither "sibling/child/descendant", it doesn't even show up in "following".

What should I use to pick out the right text?

More detailed html code:
http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/0a8c8acce7197b50c03b8f2c3bc3939d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XPath,

```
normalize-space((//dt[.="Label:"])[1]/following-sibling::dd[1])
```

will select the space-normalized string value of first immediately following `dd` element of the first `dt` element whose string value is "Label:",

```
East to West
```

as requested.